# Deleted Local codebase in Firebase. How do i retrieve the code?

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am currently developing an app in firebase and nodejs and I accidentally deleted the functions folder within firebase on my local system. The functions folder contains all the core logic of the app.

Fortunately, I had deployed my codebase by using "firebase deploy" onto the server just before this mishap occurred.

How can I get access to the codebase that is currently running on the server and download it to my local system?

Comment: Try going to console.cloud.google.com, then go to the storage browser and look in the `staging.<project_id>.appspot.com` bucket. If you see a zip file there, it might contain your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to [@Michael-Bleigh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226391/michael-bleigh) for the solution.

`console.cloud.google.com` has a list of all the functions. Under the source tab, there is an option to download the entire source to your computer.